# Error 'NoneType' object has no attribute '_default_manager' when I create a view of Model instance

Tags: django, feincms

I'm new in Django and I'm developing an app but I'm stuck in this Error.
First I want to apologize for my English since is not my first language and then I hope I'm in the right place to ask for little help.

I'm developing a website about Publication of articles. The page "Publication" return a list of the model instances - in my case all the publications in the db.

What I'm trying to do is to assign a url to each of the instances of my Model, such that the user can click on it and see the page which is populated with other relevant information of that instance.

To do this I'm using get_absolute_url in my template and DetailView in my view. 
The list of all the instance works fine but when I click on each of the instance I run the error  'NoneType' object has no attribute '_default_manager' .
I google already and try to follow some guidelines here and there, and try to find solution in Django doc couldnt figure out the solution...

Here my code:

**models.py**

```
class Publications(MPTTModel):
    code = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    date = models.DateField(null=True)
    magazine = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    country = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=150)
    img01 = models.ImageField(upload_to="photo", blank=True, null=True)
    link = models.URLField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
    template = models.ForeignKey("Template", related_name="publications", null=True, blank=True)
    parent = models.ForeignKey('self', null=True, blank=True, related_name='children')
    control_field = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Publications"
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('mag-publication',args=(self.slug,))
```

**publications.html**

```
{% load mptt_tags %}
{% load sito_tags %}
{% full_tree_for_model myApp.Publications as publications %}
{% for publications,structure in publications|tree_info %}  
    {% if publications.img01 %}
    <div id="title_publication_container">
        <a href="{{ publications.get_absolute_url }}">{{ publications.magazine }}</a>
    </div>                      
    {% else %}                          
        ....    
    {% endif %} 
{% endfor %}
```

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',  
url(r'^(?P<id_page>\d+)/(?P<slug>[\w-]+)/$', pages,),
url(r'^(?P<id_page>\d+)/(?P<slug_page>[\w-]+)/(?P<id>\d+)/(?P<slug>[\w-]+)/$', projects,),
url(r'^mag-publication/(?P<slug>[\w-]+)/$', PublicationDetailView.as_view() , name='mag-publication'),
```

)

**view.py**

```
class PublicationView(object):
    queryset = Publications.objects.all()

class PublicationListView(PublicationView, ListView):
    paginate_by = 20

class PublicationDetailView(PublicationView, DetailView):
    slug_field = 'slug'
```

The error show me this Debug informations:

```
AttributeError at /6/publications/*title_publication*/
**'NoneType' object has no attribute '_default_manager'**

Request Method:     GET
Request URL:    .../6/publications/*title_publication*/
Django Version:     1.5.4
Exception Type:     AttributeError
Exception Value:    'NoneType' object has no attribute '_default_manager'
Exception Location:     /home/gabriele/virtual_envs/virt2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/feincms/views/cbv/views.py in get_object, line 20
Python Executable:  /home/gabriele/virtual_envs/virt2/bin/python
```

Maybe the problem has something to do with feincms as it said in the "Exception Location" but everything came out after I tried to work on the instance of the Model.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Can you post your complete Publications model? Does it have some ForeignKey relations?

Comment: Hi Ankit. I add Publications Model compete. Yes, there is a Foreignkey with another Model Templates. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably didn't add `feincms.module.page` to your `INSTALLED_APPS` as per the [documentation](http://www.feinheit.ch/media/labs/feincms/installation.html#configuration). If you follow the traceback, the error appears in [get_object()](https://github.com/feincms/feincms/blob/master/feincms/views/cbv/views.py#L27) where it tries to access the page model.

Are you using an older FeinCMS version? Newer versions raise a warning in that case.

Comment: Hi Jonas. I'm using feincms 1.7.4. I added feincms.module.page to my INSTALLED_APPS but now I have this error:

 The page module requires a 'Page.register_templates()' call somewhere ('Page.register_regions()' is not sufficient). If you're not using the default Page admin, maybe try FEINCMS_USE_PAGE_ADMIN=False to avoid this warning.

Where I should add the code: 'Page.register_templates()' ?

Thanks

Comment: Any idea on this problem ?

Comment: Hi Gabriele, I'm sorry but you should really use the (quite comprehensive) [FeinCMS documentation](http://feincms-django-cms.readthedocs.org/en/latest/page.html) on the built-in Page module to get going. This is all explained right there.

Answer (score 0):

Well i don't know for feincms but in your views you have :

```
class PublicationView(object):
    queryset = Publications.objects.all()

class PublicationListView(PublicationView, ListView):
    paginate_by = 20

class PublicationDetailView(PublicationView, DetailView):
    slug_field = 'slug'
```

First of all you don't need to set the slug field if his name is already 'slug'.

And an other thing :

You inherit from PublicationView in your PublicationDetailView, but the DetailView need a single object, just try like this in your url file :

```
url(r'^mag-publication/(?P<slug>[\w-]+)/$', DetailView.as_view(model=Publications) , name='mag-publication')
```

Off course don't forget to import DetailView and Publications model into your url file.

**EDIT 20/08/2014**

In your `get_absolute_url` method you use :

```
return reverse('mag-publication',args=({'slug':self.slug}))
```

If you want to use dict for params you must use :

```
return reverse('mag-publication',kwargs={'slug':self.slug})
```

And if you want to use args you must do :

```
return reverse('mag-publication',args=(self.slug,))
```

Comment: Hei, Thanks for your help. Maybe is one step forward... but didn't solve the problem I still have the same Error.

Comment: Can you get a single publication if you use the shell ? (`python manage.py shell`)

Comment: Oh and I didn't see it the first time but, in your `get_absolute_url` method in your model you using a dict for reverse args param, try this instread `return reverse('mag-publication',args=(self.slug,))`

Comment: I tried to use the shell and it show me all the publication or one by one
>>> Publications.objects.all()

Comment: I tried to use the shell and it show me all the publication or one by one
   >>> Publications.objects.all()

Then I did the changes that you suggest to me but the Error is still there... Any idea ?

Comment: I'm gonna start a new project with your code for testing, but another question can you edit a publication in the admin ?

Comment: Yes, I'm able to edit, add, delete the publication in admin. 
(of course without add feincms.module.page in settings,as @Jonas suggest me, otherwise new errors shows up in admin too).

Comment: I solved part of the problem. I used a combination of get_absolute_url and DetailView. I can see the list of the publications but when I click to one of them the app show me the Detail of all the instances of the Model instead only one. The question is how to catch only one instance. Follow the code :
views.py
    class PublicationsDetail(DetailView):
     queryset = Publications.objects.all()
     template_name = 'website/publications_detail.html'
urls.py
        url(r'^mag-publication/(?P<slug>[\w-]+)/$', PublicationsDetail.as_view() , name='mag-publication'),

Comment: Simple, don't override the queryset property, in your case you override it and tell it "select all publications objects", in your case you don't need to override the queryset in the detailview

Comment: Thank you. But if I take out the queryset I have the error
PublicationsDetail is missing a queryset. Define PublicationsDetail.model, PublicationsDetail.queryset, or override PublicationsDetail.get_queryset().

Comment: you must at least define the model for allowing django to auto generate the queryset. juste set `model=Publications` inside your PublicationsDetail view. With this django will generate a queryset based on the url parameter, here the slug

Comment: Already did but it shows all the publications and not only the one I choose... that's the problem that I can't figure it out

Comment: So, with no queryset and only a model property in your view, you still have all publications ?

Comment: Yes. This drive me crazy. I can't really see what is wrong !

Comment: can you try this in your queryset property : queryset = Publications.objects.get(slug=self.kwargs['slug']) ?

Comment: override the get_queryset method : `def get_queryset(self)` and inside : `return Publications.objects.get(slug=self.kwargs['slug'])`

Comment: If I use

    **class PublicationsDetail(DetailView):**
     template_name = 'website/publications_detail.html'
     def get_queryset(self):
      return Publications.objects.get(slug=self.kwargs['slug'])

I get the error:
'Publications' object has no attribute 'filter'
If I do
return Publications.objects.filter(slug=self.kwargs['slug'])
it works but, of course, give me all the Publications

Answer (score 0):

I solved part of the problem. I used a combination of get_absolute_url and DetailView. 
I can see the perfectly the list of the publications in publication.html but when I click to one of them the app show me - in publications_detail.html -  the detail of all the instances of the Model instead only one. 
From publications in admin "view on site" it works but there's the same problem, show me all the instances together.
The question is how to catch only one instance. Follow the code :

**models.py**

```
class Publications(MPTTModel):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=150)
    img01 = models.ImageField(upload_to="photo", blank=True, null=True) 
    template = models.ForeignKey("Template", related_name="publications", null=True, blank=True)
    parent = models.ForeignKey('self', null=True, blank=True, related_name='children')
    control_field = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Publications"
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('mag-publication',args=(self.slug,))
```

**views.py**

```
class PublicationsDetail(DetailView): 
    queryset = Publications.objects.all() 
    template_name = 'website/publications_detail.html'
```

**urls.py**

```
url(r'^mag-publication/(?P<slug>[\w-]+)/$', PublicationsDetail.as_view()
```

**publications_detail.html**

```
{% load mptt_tags %}
{% load sito_tags %}
{% full_tree_for_model napeApp.Publications as publications %}
{% for publications,structure in publications|tree_info %}  
    {% if publications.img01 %}
        <div id="title_publication_container">
        <a href="{{ publications.get_absolute_url }}">{{ publications.magazine     }}</a>
        </div>                      
    {% else %}
    ....        
    {% endif %} 
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case I just renamed meta to Meta and it solved.maybe it is related to sensitive capital class name